# $[\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{K}),\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{K})] = \mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{K})$

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. How do I proove that: $[\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{K}),\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{K})] = \mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{K})$?

I know that it is easy to see that $[\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{K}),\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{K})] \subset \mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{K})$, since the trace vanishes over the product Lie Algebra, however the other inclusion does not work out for me. I know that I could go ahead and compute a minmal generator out of the set $[v_i,v_j]$, where $v_i$ is a basis for $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{K})$, but this does not seem like a beautiful proove to me. Is there an elegant way to see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_{ij}\in\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb K)$ be the matrix with a single $1$ in the $(i,j)$-component. Then, it suffices to check that $e_{ij},e_{ii}-e_{jj}\in[\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb K),\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb K)]$ (where $i\ne j$).

We have $e_{ii}-e_{jj}=[e_{ij},e_{ji}]$. I will leave expressing $e_{ij}$ similarly in terms of brackets to you as an exercise.

Comment: We get that $e_{ij}= [e_{ii},e_{ij}]$ for $i \neq j$, from which we can conclude the result since we now have a basis of $\mathfrak{sl}$ in our set, correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)\cong \mathfrak{sl}_n(K)\oplus Z$, see below, where $Z$ is the center of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$, we obtain
$$
[\mathfrak{gl}_n(K),\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)]=[\mathfrak{sl}_n(K),\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)]\oplus[\mathfrak{sl}_n(K),Z]\oplus [Z,Z]=\mathfrak{sl}_n(K).
$$
Here the commutator of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ is $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$, because the Lie algebra is simple and the commutator is a nonzero ideal.

[Proving that $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{F})=\mathfrak{sl}(n, \mathbb{F}) \oplus \mathfrak{s}(n,\mathbb{F})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4461225/proving-that-mathfrakgln-mathbbf-mathfraksln-mathbbf-mathfr?rq=1)

Comment: How do you show $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ is simple?

Comment: @KentaS There is an elementary proof, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598356/how-to-show-that-mathfraksl-n-mathbbr-and-mathfraksl-n-mathbbc).

Comment: By the way, you could have just said $[\mathfrak{gl}_n,\mathfrak{gl}_n]\subset\mathfrak{sl}_n$ is an ideal.

Comment: Yes, but the fact $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)\cong \mathfrak{sl}_n(K)\oplus Z$ is of independent interest. It implies this and many other things easily.

Comment: I think this is a matter of philosophy, whether or not one should use certain facts in proofs. I personally believe when first learning a subject, a more direct argument is oftentimes more illuminating.

Comment: Yes, but the OP explicitly asked not only the direct way, but also "Is there an elegant way to see this?". After you have explained the direct way, there was only to add some "certain facts", as you say. And I still think, they are helpful for the further study.

Comment: Indeed this answer has answered me another question, why $[\mathfrak{sl}_n(K), \mathfrak{sl}_n(K)] = \mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ without showing that the basis is included, so thank you for that! Even though I kind of need to learn further now, since these examples in my book were given before we talked about simple lie algebras.